# " #SingleInstance force " is being ignored

Tags: autohotkey

## SingleInstance force

is supposed to prevent the popup when I tell the script to reload... but it doesn't. I'm still getting the warning that a copy of the script is already running. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code, there are a few things I can think of that might be interfering. The first is that there may be a typo. Please verify that it is exactly `#SingleInstance force`. Another thing could be that it is not placed near the beginning of the script; possibly after a `Return`. Finally, from the help file,

> AutoHotkey relies on the title of the script's main window to
>   identify other running instances of the script.

Is this script calling another script or is there anything the might affect the script name? If none of these things helps, it might be a good idea to post your code or at least a portion of it so we can better see what's going on.

Comment: You were right, it wasn't actually my script it was windowpad, adding the single instance to windowpad eliminated the error. Thanks!